# passing array as argument in java

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

i wants to pass array as arguments to sub class from main . but looks like its not initialized.Please have a look on below and advice where i am wrong.
Thanks in Advance

```
    class arraymain{
    public static void main(String[] arg){

        Array obj=new Array();
        obj.passArray(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5},4);
    }
    }
 class Array{
 void passArray(int[] values,int size){

   values=new int[size];
        for (int num=0;num<values.length;num++){
            System.out.println(values[num]);

        }
    }

}
OUPTPUT:
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Isn't it because of this line `values=new int[size];`? You are overriding whatever is being passed.

Comment: There's also no reason to pass the `size` parameter.

Comment: You are not supposed to assign a value to a parameter variable, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Side note on code quality: I understand that you are just beginning, but please spend some time up front to read about basic java concepts; for example to how name classes, methods, ... ( see here fore example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334204/official-java-code-guidelines-conventions )

Comment: ok sir  i will read that.;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `values=new int[size];` from your `Array` class.

You are getting `values` as parameter, and then you are doing this `values=new int[size];`, which creates a new array, and this new array has no values (default values 0).

Comment: yeah that works . but i wants to set size of array in sub class.can you please explain how i can do that

Comment: "No values" isn't quite right. It has its default values, which are zeros.

Comment: yeah its right buddy . but in my assignment i need to pass array size as argument.

Comment: @PreetSingh, you already have a size, why do you need to set the size again?

Comment: @PreetSingh my comment wasn't for you, it was for Soumitri and is about a statement in his answer. :)

Comment: @AnilReddy arrays don't have a 'length()' method. They have a 'length' attribute/field :P.

Comment: Thanks  to everybody for explain

Answer (score 4):

```
values=new int[size];
```

You are initializing a new array, overwriting the passed parameter.

When creating a new array this way, all values are initialized with their default values, for `int` this happens to be 0.

Simply remove this line, and the code should work as intended.

And, as a comment points out, this makes the parameter `size` unused. The *length* of the array is derived directly from the array, as you already do in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line

```
values=new int[size]
```

You are creating a **new** array, and thereby you are hiding the one with non-0 values.